# Binary relation of composite function

Tags: functions, relations

Suppose S is a binary relation on a set X.  If S ◦ S is reflexive, Is S is reflexive? can we   prove this  with example too and by definition "Let U be a non-empty set and let R be a binary relation on R is reflexive if ∀x ∈ U, (x, x) ∈ R.

Answer (score 0):

There is atleast one case where it does not hold.

Consider $S = \{(a,b),(b,a)\}$

Then $S \circ S = \{(a,a),(b,b)\}$ i.e reflexive even though $S$ is not

Comment: How we can with definition or as theorem

Comment: I do not understand what you mean

Comment: sorry for the confusion I mean can we prove without a example through definition of Reflexive .
"Let U be a non-empty set and let R be a binary relation on U
R is reflexive if ∀x ∈ U, (x, x) ∈ R."

Answer (score 0):

Well you could check if S is an equivalence relation or if there is some "partial order relation" on S, because this would then imply that S is reflexive by definition.